# Will VSTO add-ins developed for Office 2007 work in Office 2010?

Tags: vsto, ms-office, office-2010

Are the VSTO add-ins that were developed for Office 2007 compatible with Office 2010? If not, what would need to be done to upgrade them to run in 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2009/08/05/will-your-vsto-addin-run-on-office-2010-64-bit-yes-probably-christin-boyd.aspx).

Comment: agreed, ribbon is still there, and while deprecated nothing ever really gets removed from the major object models.

Comment: @Otaku but how about the other way around? I mean, will my Excel 2010 add-in work in Excel 2007?

Comment: @woodykiddy: yes, it's certainly doable from VSTO 2010, provided you target .NET 4.0. See this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to this (german) blog nothing big will change:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/jensha/archive/2008/11/14/vsto-next.aspx

So I think it is save to say that it will work (althoug I would recommend to upgrade the code due mayor improvements in VSTO.NE(X)T).

Answer (score 0):

I think VSTO 3.0 will not. Developed with VSTO 4.0 can.